# Adding hyperlinks in element notes Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, element, enterprise-architect

I am working on Enterprise Architect C# add-ins. I am trying to add hyperlink to another package in element notes through add-ins as shown below:

[image: package hyperlink]

I found the code for adding hyperlink in element to package here : https://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php?topic=4068.0
and tried the following code:

```
                    EA.Package parentPkg = Session.Repository.GetPackageByID(currentPackage.ParentID);//target package
                    hyperlink = currentPackage.Elements.AddNew("$package://"+parentPkg.PackageGUID, "Text"); //adding hyperlink
                    hyperlink.Update();
                    hyperlink.Subtype = 19; 
                    hyperlink.Update();
                    hyperlink.Notes = parentPkg.Name;
                    hyperlink.Update();
                    demoElement.Notes = "test for packages hyperlinks" + hyperlink; //demo element's notes must contain hyperlink to target package
                    mobjElement.Update();
```

It is not displayed as hyperlink here but as System.__ComObject.
Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a difference between a hyperlink element and a hyperlink in the notes. The first is an EA.Element, the latter is just fancy text.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Thank you..can you please tell if it possible to add hyperlink in notes through EA API

Comment: Just inspect the contents of the notes field in the database, and do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Geert and Thomas Suggested if you just need to make hyperlink in notes just add a herf tag ti that word like below

```
This is a <a href="$element://{64162D99-026B-40b3-914C-2CC009943540}"><font
     color="#0000ff"><u>Hyperlink</u></font> </a> Example
```

and the output in notes will be like

[image]

In API you can just add the link text in notes property of any class.

```
switch ( treeSelectedType )
    {
        case otElement :
        {
            // Code for when an element is selected
            var theElement as EA.Element;
            theElement = Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject();
            theElement.Notes="This is a <a href=\"$element://{700ED461-FAC6-4097-AFF5-5F4787AD99CB}\"><font color=\"#0000ff\"><u>Hyperlink</u></font></a>  Example";
            theElement.Update();
            theElement.Refresh();



            break;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think the call to `Refresh()` is necessary.

Comment: @GeertBellekens@ThomasKilian@Arshad..Thank you..it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I tried (as Geert suggested) the following code snippet (sorry for the Perl):

```
my $e = $rep->getElementByGuid("{92EF2B52-B75E-454d-AD03-5BDC12256A36}");
$e->{notes} = "<a href=\"\$package://{81657422-5D41-4dbf-9210-461DF67FD2C2}\"><font color=\"#0000ff\"><u>Link name</u></font></a>";
$e->Update();
```

Just replace the GUID and the display name and you have a hyperlink to a package. Note that the above string has some escape chars, so here's the raw text:

```
<a href="$package://{81657422-5D41-4dbf-9210-461DF67FD2C2}"><font color="#0000ff"><u>Link name</u></font></a>
```